# Store Orion data via Cygnus

Tags: fiware, fiware-orion, fiware-cygnus

I'm using Orion (2.2.0) and Cygnus (1.9.0) to store data in MySQL. It worked using `attrsFormat: 'legacy'` in the subscription payload. 
My question is this: could I install the new version of Cygnus to without usage of attrsFormat = legacy?

Thanks a lot
Pasquale

Answer (score 1):

Cygnus support for NGSIv2 (which would avoid the usage of `"attrsFormat": "legacy"`) will be available in the next version of Cygnus (1.18.0).

In fact, the PR implementing the functionality has been merged this afternoon :), so if you are in a hurry, you can use Cygnus from master branch (`:latest` tag if you grab it from dockerhub) and test it. Any feedback is welcome!

Comment: Thank you, I can wait for the 1.18.0 release. I'm going to replace my old version and I'll test it

Comment: I tried with successful the NGSI v2 (notification) for 1.17.0_SNAPSHOT version Cygnus. For info: I installed Cygnus from sources and I had to use a flavor medium (of my VM) and to increase the memory of JVM. I'll wait for the next version (1.18.0) because I want to replace it in my architecture.

Comment: I'm going also to create a script (bash file) so you can install automatically Cygnus.

Comment: I confirm that 1.18.0 supports NGSIv2 (of course without "attrsFormat": "legacy" in the subscription payload). When can I install the new version directly using yum install?

Comment: @pasquy73 I think this question goes to the FIWARE Foundation, that are the ones that keep the public RPM yum repositories for FIWARE GEs, like Cygnus. I'm afraid I cannot provide an answer on that (although I'd like to know such answer if they provide to you, please post it in this comments thread :)

Comment: Anyway, I'd recommend you to upgrade to lastest Cygnus version (2.1.0 in the moment of writing this). Time has passed and 1.18.0 is now old :)